# Joomla Extension Installation

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm developing an extension (module) that I want to be compatible with Joomla 1.5, 2.5 and 3.0 if possible. My main issue is getting around the different XML files needed. I decided to create a `manifest.xml` file for Joomla 1.5 with the `<install>` tag and a `mod_mymodule.xml` file for Joomla 2.5/3.0 with a `<extension>` tag with the `mod_mymodule.xml` containing fieldsets etc. whilst the `manifest.xml` contains the `<params>`.

My issue is that my extension installs absolutely fine on Joomla 3.0 (on localhost). However when installing on a Joomla 2.5, nothing showed up under the parameters. What is the priority for Joomla 2.5 and why it using the `manifest.xml` file with the install tags instead of the `mod_mymodule.xml` file?

Does Joomla 2.5 prioritize an `<install>` tag at the top of an XML file over another XML file in the same directory with an `<extension>` tag?

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install type="module" client="site" method="upgrade" version="1.5">
    <name></name> 
    <author>George Wilson</author> 
    <creationDate>05-Mar-2012</creationDate> 
    <copyright></copyright> 
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html</license> 
    <authorEmail></authorEmail> 
    <authorUrl></authorUrl> 
    <version>1.1.1</version> 
    <description></description>
    <files>
            <filename module="mod_mymodule">mod_mymodule.php</filename>
            <filename>manifest.xml</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>helper.php</filename>
            <folder>assets</folder>
            <folder>tmpl</folder>
    </files>

    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
    </languages>

    <params>
        <param name="blah" type="text" default="5" label="Label" description="Description" />
    </params>
</install>
```

mod_mymodule.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name></name> 
    <author>George Wilson</author> 
    <creationDate>05-Mar-2012</creationDate> 
    <copyright></copyright> 
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html</license> 
    <authorEmail></authorEmail> 
    <authorUrl></authorUrl> 
    <version>1.1.1</version> 
    <description>Description</description>
    <files>
            <filename module="mod_mymodule">mod_mymodule.php</filename>
            <filename>mod_mymodule.xml</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>helper.php</filename>
            <folder>assets</folder>
            <folder>sql</folder>
            <folder>tmpl</folder>
    </files>

    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>

    <install>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </install>
    <uninstall>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </uninstall>

    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="moduleclass_sfx" type="text" default="" label="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_LABEL" description="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_DESC" />
            </fieldset>                 
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Errors:
Beneath position parameter:
    ( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ROOT\administrator\components\com_modules\views\module\tmpl\edit.php on line 50

Beneath ordering parameter
    ( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\joomla25\administrator\components\com_modules\views\module\tmpl\edit.php on line 61

It also says `Module XML data not available` at the bottom.

**Update:** Upon inspection it is definitely the `manifest.xml` file that is installing rather than the `mod_mymodule.xml` that I want the Joomla 2.5 to use.

Comment: which parameter you not seen component or module, you can use <install> tag but in parameter there are difference j 1.5 support parameters using <params> and j 2.5 using <config><fields> so try with these tags or give some example of your code of xmls

Comment: Updated my question to specify its a module. My point is that in the manifest.xml I want for J1.5 compat so is using <params>. And the mod_mymodule.xml I want for J2.5/3.0 and is using <config><fieldset><fields>. However this isn't working in J2.5

Comment: can i see your manifest and also your module files struture for 2.5

Comment: Yeah will chuck it up tonight when I get back to my laptop I have it all stored on!

Comment: @RakeshSharma put the file information you requested up. Removed some of the details. But the xml files are definately OK. Cause they install fine on Joomla 1.5 and Joomla 3.0. And the module installs without errors in 2.5. But then I find when I go to edit the module no params and the errors listed on the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

struture of both should be manifest.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install type="module" version="2.5" method="upgrade">
     <name>my module</name> 
    <author>George Wilson</author> 
    <creationDate>05-Mar-2012</creationDate> 
    <copyright></copyright> 
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html</license> 
    <authorEmail></authorEmail> 
    <authorUrl></authorUrl> 
    <version>1.1.1</version> 
    <description>Description</description>

    <!-- Installation -->   
    <!--<install>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">mod_mymodule/sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </install>
    <installfile>install/install.php</installfile>
    <uninstall>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">mod_mymodule/sql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </uninstall>
    <uninstallfile>install/uninstall.php</uninstallfile>

    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodule.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>-->

    <!-- Modules -->
            <files folder="mod_mymodule">
                <filename module="mod_mymodule">mod_mymodule.php</filename>
                <filename>mod_mymodule.xml</filename>
                <!--<filename>index.html</filename>
                <filename>helper.php</filename>
                <folder>assets</folder>
                <folder>sql</folder>
                <folder>tmpl</folder>-->        
            </files>
</install>
```

And the module file should be module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" client="site" method="upgrade" version="2.5">
    <name>my module</name> 
    <author>George Wilson</author> 
    <creationDate>05-Mar-2012</creationDate> 
    <copyright></copyright> 
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html</license> 
    <authorEmail></authorEmail> 
    <authorUrl></authorUrl> 
    <version>1.1.1</version> 
    <description></description>
    <files>
            <filename module="mod_mymodule">mod_mymodule.php</filename>
            <filename>mod_mymodule.xml</filename>
           <!-- <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>helper.php</filename>
            <folder>assets</folder>
            <folder>tmpl</folder>-->
    </files>

    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="moduleclass_sfx" type="text" default="" label="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_LABEL" description="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_DESC" />
            </fieldset>                 
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

hope this help you only change params for 1.5 teated on my demo and commit out if you want include some more file please create a module package and your sturuture sholu be

a. manifest.xml
b. mod_mymodule (dir) and zip both in one. not add manifest in module folder

Comment: Thankyou for the repsonse! when you say "struture of both should be manifest.xml" will this then work on 3.0 as in the mod_mymodule.xml file I see you've commented out the <filename> etc section

Comment: yes it required for manifest know module installation, it's working on your end?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work so ended up splitting up the 1.5 and 2.5/3.0 versions so that I could incorporate the joomla update features etc. Thanks for the help though! Marked it as correct so someone can use it as a starting point!

Answer (score 0):

Your second xml is missing the version (joomla! version, not your extension). Please see below:

```
    <extension type="module" client="site" method="upgrade" version="2.5">
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I tried it but it still didn't work on 2.5 - it was still installing the manifest.xml rather than the other xml file. However still good to add in for completeness